# Laravel Thermal printer not responding

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, thermal-printer

I am developing an app which uses thermal printer

I am using windows 10 and printer is Xprinter Xp-58IIH

The printer is connected to my system using usb

The print does not respond to printing and no error is showing on the log

web.php

```
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\NetworkPrintConnector;

   try {      

    $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("Xp-58IIH");
    $printer = new Escpos($connector);
    $printer->text("Hello World!\n");
    $printer->cut();

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Couldn't print to this printer: " . $e -> getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

[image]

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Pleas have a look at this...

https://github.com/charlieuki/receipt-printer

Installation
Via Composer

```
$ composer require charlieuki/receiptprinter
```

Sample App
I have set up a simple app based on Laravel 7 to serve as a demo.

Usage
Execute the following command to publish the config used by this package:

```
$ php artisan vendor:publish --tag=receiptprinter.config
```

Edit the config file located at config/receiptprinter.php as follows:

Set connector_type to:

windows if you are using Windows as your web server.
cups if you are using Linux or Mac as your web server.
network if you are using a network printer.

Set connector_descriptor to:

the printer name if your connector_type is either windows or cups
the IP address or Samba URI, e.g: smb://192.168.0.5/PrinterName if your connector_type is network

Set connector_port to the open port for the printer, only if your connector_type is network

Include the library:

```
use charlieuki\ReceiptPrinter\ReceiptPrinter as ReceiptPrinter;
```

Then use any one of these two functions to send "print" command to the printer.

```
printReceipt()
printRequest()
```

**Example (Print Receipt)**

```
use charlieuki\ReceiptPrinter\ReceiptPrinter as ReceiptPrinter;
    
    ...

// Set params
$mid = '123123456';
$store_name = 'YOURMART';
$store_address = 'Mart Address';
$store_phone = '1234567890';
$store_email = 'yourmart@email.com';
$store_website = 'yourmart.com';
$tax_percentage = 10;
$transaction_id = 'TX123ABC456';
$currency = 'Rp';

// Set items
$items = [
    [
        'name' => 'French Fries (tera)',
        'qty' => 2,
        'price' => 65000,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Roasted Milk Tea (large)',
        'qty' => 1,
        'price' => 24000,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Honey Lime (large)',
        'qty' => 3,
        'price' => 10000,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Jasmine Tea (grande)',
        'qty' => 3,
        'price' => 8000,
    ],
];

// Init printer
$printer = new ReceiptPrinter;
$printer->init(
    config('receiptprinter.connector_type'),
    config('receiptprinter.connector_descriptor')
);

// Set store info
$printer->setStore($mid, $store_name, $store_address, $store_phone, $store_email, $store_website);

// Set currency
$printer->setCurrency($currency);

// Add items
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $printer->addItem(
        $item['name'],
        $item['qty'],
        $item['price']
    );
}
// Set tax
$printer->setTax($tax_percentage);

// Calculate total
$printer->calculateSubTotal();
$printer->calculateGrandTotal();

// Set transaction ID
$printer->setTransactionID($transaction_id);

// Set qr code
$printer->setQRcode([
    'tid' => $transaction_id,
]);

// Print receipt
$printer->printReceipt();
Example (Print Request)
use charlieuki\ReceiptPrinter\ReceiptPrinter as ReceiptPrinter;

...

// Set params
$mid = '123123456';
$store_name = 'YOURMART';
$store_address = 'Mart Address';
$store_phone = '1234567890';
$store_email = 'yourmart@email.com';
$store_website = 'yourmart.com';
$tax_percentage = 10;
$transaction_id = 'TX123ABC456';
$currency = 'Rp';

// Init printer
$printer = new ReceiptPrinter;
$printer->init(
    config('receiptprinter.connector_type'),
    config('receiptprinter.connector_descriptor')
);

// Set store info
$printer->setStore($mid, $store_name, $store_address, $store_phone, $store_email, $store_website);

// Set currency
$printer->setCurrency($currency);

// Set request amount
$printer->setRequestAmount($request_amount);

// Set transaction ID
$printer->setTransactionID($transaction_id);

// Set qr code
$printer->setQRcode([
    'tid' => $transaction_id,
    'amount' => $request_amount,
]);

// Print payment request
$printer->printRequest();
```